# overlay over the video in artoolkit

Tags: c, xcode, opengl, artoolkit

I need to show some information and create some polygons over the video in simpleVRML example in ARToolKit.
Can i create a openGL window and make a overlay window over the video layer of simpleVRML?
How can i do that?